# RequireJs and Jsx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, requirejs

I use RequireJs and React, when i load jsx from local machine everything works fine, the problem starts when i try to load jsx files from another domain,

Example: 
say we have a file named Flight.jsx,

accessing localhost loads jsx correctly-> localhost/Flight.jsx -> file exists,

changing the hosts file so 127.0.0.1 will lead to mydomain.com

accessing mydomain.com and the result is that RequireJs tries to get Flight.jsx  from: 
mydomain.com/Flight.jsx.js -> that file doesn't exists

How can i fix it?
What am i missing?

Comment: When using the files you use relative addressing?

Comment: In your example you're saying RequireJs can't find `mydomain.com/Flight.jsx.js` but it should be looking for `mydomain.com/Flight.jsx`, no? Is that a typo in your code or in your question?

Comment: Ali, In the requireJs.config i define the baseUrl as mydomain.com , Danny: It looks for mydomain.com/Flight.jsx.js, when the real file name is mydomain.com/Flight.jsx